# Laravel Websockets sent and received messages do not show up

Tags: laravel, websocket, laravel-websockets

I am using Beyondcodes laravel-websockets lib to implement websockets functionality to my app. However when I connect to the ws server (locally) I only get connect and disconnect messages. Whenever I broadcast something from the backend it only shows up in the laravel-websockets dashboard. I tried multiple ws clients (including postman) and they do not show up the broadcasted messages - only the connection/disconnection messages. whenever I send a message though ws clients they do not show up in the laravel-websockets dashboard also. What can the issue be here?

Edit: I am using docker for the project and I have opened the 6001 port.

This is the laravel code I use. I am using what laravel provides out of the box:

```
public function broadcastOn()
{
    return new Channel('my-channel');
}
```

And this is how I trigger the event:

```
event(new ConfirmationRequest(['data' => $data]));
```

No other code that I can provide since I am using a package and Postman for testing the connection. As I said: All messages show up in the /laravel-websocket route dashboard but in other ws clients the only messages I get are connection/dissconect

Comment: With no code, its hard to help.

Comment: Do you sibscribe to channels pn frontend?

Comment: @JoshBolton i have added code in the question now